# at loss with return value from list(), do I need to convert a tuple into a string?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to answer a question.
The question is one the same line as the answer in a file the user selects, the program will then select the line at random, split the line and put the two items in seperate return variables.

I am at a loss when comparing the variables at the end, though. I suspect that I am trying to compare a str with a tuple, and that's why it's not working. I am of course a newbie and came this far by searching the forum, but now I need your help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import random
import operator

def random_line(file):
    return random.choice(list(open(file)))

def seperate_values(a):
    line = a
    lst = line.split()
    question = list([lst[i] for i in [0]])
    answer = list([lst[i] for i in [1]])
    return question, answer



current_list = raw_input("Please enter filename\n")
chosen_line = random_line(current_list)

chosen_question, chosen_answer = seperate_values(chosen_line)

print chosen_question
print chosen_answer
user_answer = raw_input("enter the 3-digit code please\n")

if user_answer == chosen_answer:
    print "congratulations"
else:
    print "failure"
```

the file that is being read is a txt that looks like this:

```
auckland akl
wellington wlg
taupo tuo
hamilton hlz
```

Comment: What's the format of the file it's reading? Can you post an example file?

Comment: it's a simple txt with multiple lines that look like this: auckland akl

Comment: BTW, if you intend to expand the program so that it asks multiple questions from the file you should fix that `random_line()' function, so that it doesn't have to open the file, read its contents, and create a list of lines _every_ time you want a new random line.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Replace

```
question = list([lst[i] for i in [0]])
answer = list([lst[i] for i in [1]])
```

with

```
question = lst[0]
answer = lst[1]
```

Or, better, replace

```
line = a
lst = line.split()
question = list([lst[i] for i in [0]])
answer = list([lst[i] for i in [1]])
return question, answer
```

with

```
question, answer = a.split()
return question, answer
```

---

In more depth, let us examine this expression: `list([lst[i] for i in [0]])`. We have a list comprehension that is then passed into `list`. But a list comprehension already creates a list, so passing it into `list` then creates a copy with the same contents as the first. So this is the same as `[lst[i] for i in [0]]`. What’s that doing? Well, for each `i` in `[0]`, we have an item, `lst[i]`. There’s only one `i`, `0`, so it’s creating a list with one element, `lst[0]`. But you probably wanted the item itself, not a list with that as a single element, so you should just use `lst[0]` if you want that element.

But then I went further and used unpacking. See, the unpacking notation is not exclusive to tuples: no, it can be used on lists, too, and we can even just put the `split` on the right side, condensing it to my last suggested change.

If you wanted to, you could even simplify the function down to this:

```
return a.split()
```

But I like the clarity imparted by the destructuring into `question` and `answer`.

Comment: brilliant, I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in lines 10 & 11:

```
question = list([lst[i] for i in [0]])
answer = list([lst[i] for i in [1]])
```

I don't know what ^%*&#^ you're trying to do here but you're ending up with two lists, not two strings. You could simplify this greatly:

```
question = lst[0]
answer = lst[1]
```

And then it will work because it'll get two strings, the first and second words on a given line in the file.

Comment: thank you very much. I was trying to grab a specific item from a list, and that's the only line of code that I could find. However, now I get this error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: That's because you've probably used round brackets instead of square ones.